# Comparing List/Make-list & Vector/Make-array in Common Lisp

Tags: assembly, common-lisp, x86-64, compiler-optimization, sbcl

The assembly code for `list` and `make-list` is somewhat different (in SBCL), even when the end results are the same:

```
* (disassemble (lambda (x) (list x)))
; disassembly for (LAMBDA (X))
; Size: 77 bytes. Origin: #x10025C0064
; 64:       498B4560         MOV RAX, [R13+96]                ; no-arg-parsing entry point
                                                              ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; 68:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX
; 6C:       840425F8FF1020   TEST AL, [#x2010FFF8]            ; safepoint
; 73:       4D8B5D20         MOV R11, [R13+32]                ; thread.alloc-region
; 77:       498D4310         LEA RAX, [R11+16]
; 7B:       493B4528         CMP RAX, [R13+40]
; 7F:       7725             JNBE L1
; 81:       49894520         MOV [R13+32], RAX                ; thread.alloc-region
; 85: L0:   498D4307         LEA RAX, [R11+7]
; 89:       840425F8FF1020   TEST AL, [#x2010FFF8]            ; safepoint
; 90:       488950F9         MOV [RAX-7], RDX
; 94:       C7400117001120   MOV DWORD PTR [RAX+1], #x20110017  ; NIL
; 9B:       488BD0           MOV RDX, RAX
; 9E:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; A1:       F8               CLC
; A2:       5D               POP RBP
; A3:       C3               RET
; A4:       CC0F             BREAK 15                         ; Invalid argument count trap
; A6: L1:   6A10             PUSH 16
; A8:       FF142528000020   CALL QWORD PTR [#x20000028]      ; ALLOC-TRAMP-R11
; AF:       EBD4             JMP L0
NIL

* (disassemble (lambda (x) (make-list 1 :initial-element x)))
; disassembly for (LAMBDA (X))
; Size: 43 bytes. Origin: #x10025C0127
; 27:       498B5D60         MOV RBX, [R13+96]                ; no-arg-parsing entry point
                                                              ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; 2B:       48895DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RBX
; 2F:       840425F8FF1020   TEST AL, [#x2010FFF8]            ; safepoint
; 36:       BA02000000       MOV EDX, 2
; 3B:       488BFE           MOV RDI, RSI
; 3E:       488B0593FFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-109]               ; #<SB-KERNEL:FDEFN SB-KERNEL:%MAKE-LIST>
; 45:       B904000000       MOV ECX, 4
; 4A:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
; 4D:       FF6009           JMP QWORD PTR [RAX+9]
; 50:       CC0F             BREAK 15                         ; Invalid argument count trap
NIL
*
```

Note however that `(disassemble (lambda (x) (cons x nil)))` and `(disassemble (lambda (x) (list x)))` seem to produce the same code.

The same kind of difference shows up for `(disassemble (lambda (x) (vector x)))` and `(disassemble (lambda (x) (make-array 1 :initial-element x)))`.

Is one of `list` or `make-list` (and `vector` or `make-array`) more efficient following compiler optimization?

Also, is one of `list` or `vector` (and `make-list` or `make-array`) more efficient (ignoring for the moment how the sequences are subsequently accessed and updated)?

Comment: `MAKE-LIST` calls the function `SB-KERNEL:%MAKE-LIST`

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit unclear to me how (say) `list` and `make-list` can be compared, since they have completely different purposes. The fact that they both return a list doesn't make them similar or comparable.

Hence, suppose one wants to get some idea of how `make-list` performs. The following code does that:

```
* (let ((lst (time (make-list 10000000 :initial-element 0)))) (if lst t nil))
Evaluation took:
  0.344 seconds of real time
  0.343750 seconds of total run time (0.187500 user, 0.156250 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.251 seconds GC time, and 0.093 seconds non-GC time. ]
  100.00% CPU
  1,129,211,079 processor cycles
  160,170,016 bytes consed

T
* (let ((lst (time (make-list 10000000 :initial-element 0)))) (if lst t nil))
Evaluation took:
  0.188 seconds of real time
  0.187500 seconds of total run time (0.125000 user, 0.062500 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.139 seconds GC time, and 0.049 seconds non-GC time. ]
  100.00% CPU
  632,759,465 processor cycles
  160,195,440 bytes consed

T
* (let ((lst (time (make-list 10000000 :initial-element 0)))) (if lst t nil))
Evaluation took:
  0.343 seconds of real time
  0.343750 seconds of total run time (0.187500 user, 0.156250 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.266 seconds GC time, and 0.078 seconds non-GC time. ]
  100.29% CPU
  1,151,984,724 processor cycles
  160,170,016 bytes consed

T
* (let ((lst (time (make-list 10000000 :initial-element 0)))) (if lst t nil))
Evaluation took:
  0.203 seconds of real time
  0.203125 seconds of total run time (0.171875 user, 0.031250 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.140 seconds GC time, and 0.064 seconds non-GC time. ]
  100.00% CPU
  648,536,502 processor cycles
  160,195,520 bytes consed

T
```

The first thing to notice is that the execution times are inconsistent, because there's too much else 'randomly' going on in the system besides (such as GC). More importantly, how do we now write a 10,000,000 list of 0s to pass on to `list` for comparison? Do we use a loop (in which case it is the loop we would {mostly} be timing)? Do we first create the printed representation a 10,000,000 long list of 0s, to then be read with `read` (in which case we would be timing {mostly} the creation of the printed representation and the lisp reader)? Looks to me like apples and oranges...

Comment: Would it be possible to get a more direct comparison using `make-sequence` requesting either a 'list or 'vector?

Comment: `make-list`, `make-vector` and `make-sequence` are birds of a feather. `list` and `vector` are different animals. Both categories produce sequences, but from different premises. The former functions produce sequences with repeats of the same `initial-element`; the later of any objects you explicitly or programatically provide.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for an informed comparison between something like `(disassemble (lambda (x) (make-list 1 :initial-element x)))` and `(disassemble (lambda (x) (make-array 1 :initial-element x)`

Comment: Your question showcased disassembled `list` vs `make-list`. You are now talking of `make-list` vs `make-array`. This is a different question. It amount to querying the merits of lists vs arrays -- though possibly more narrowly in terms of the efficiency of their SBCL respective implementations. Even so, this is a vast subject (which usually boils down to "horses for courses").

Comment: Check the last statement in my original question. And yes, I know there are list/vector tradeoffs. I want to go deeper by starting with creation only (list, vector, make-list, make-sequence, make-array). Glad to have your insights if you can analyze SBCL assembly (or suggest other run-time comparisons like you first mentioned).

Comment: Find SBCL source at https://sourceforge.net/projects/sbcl/files/sbcl/ - Extract. For lists: sbcl-1.5.4/src/code/list.lisp - For arrays and vectors: sbcl-1.5.4/src/code/array.lisp - For generic sequences: sbcl-1.5.4/src/code/seq.lisp

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding make-list and make-array are more efficient following compiler optimization. For example, with make-list, you control the size of that list as soon as it is created and when you disassemble the function you should see an "invalid-args-count-error" which should optimize your code. You declare the size of that list from the beginning, whereas using the list function has no such optimization besides the limitations of the maximum size of a  list:

```
(setq x (make-list 4 :initial-element 'a))
```

compared to

```
(setq x (list 'a 'a 'a 'a))
```

An index too large error would occur if you tried to add an element to index 5 with make-list, whereas this ill not occur when creating a list with the list function. Cons would breakdown the way you described and is more similar to list or vector because there's no restriction on size and type:

```
(cons 1 '(a b c d e))
```

Compared to:

```
(make-array '(2 3) :initial-element nil
                   :element-type 'fixnum)
```

Which would limit size and only create pointers to fixnums. As far as code optimization go make-array and make-list are more efficient, but you could of course declaim that a vector will be a certain type and a certain size which will optimize your code:

```
(declaim (type (vector fixnum 20) v))
```

After that compiler optimization vector should be just as efficient as a function such as make-array before it is sent to be read.

Comment: *An index too large error would occur if you tried to add an element to index 5 with make-list, whereas this ill not occur when creating a list with the list function.* Do you have an example of this? With `(list 'a 'a 'a 'a)` the compiler knows the size of the list (there are four arguments being given), whereas make-list takes the size as an argument to be evaluated (constant propagation could help, but in general the size is unknown at compile-time).